# DHCP not functioning after wireless router firmware update

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, firmware

I own an [ASUS RT AC1200](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RT-AC1200/HelpDesk_Download/) wireless router that has been working wonderfully for 1.5 years. Last night I was fiddling with the settings via the control panel (accessible through http://router.asus.com) and it gave me a warning that I should upgrade the firmware version. I followed the steps, and now I'm on firmware 3.0.0.4.380_10574

Everything seemed to work fine, as if it had been restored to its factory settings. However, I don't get connection to the internet because of this issue:

[image]

I then tested my modem's internet connection via Ethernet, and it worked just fine. I *do* have internet connection; It's my router that's not connecting. I followed the troubleshooting steps, but got stuck on the "trying to detect the connection type" screen repeatedly for about 15 minutes at a time with no resolution:

[image]

As a networking newbie, what are my choices here? I tried resetting the router multiple times, to no avail. Are there manual settings I can input in the control panel so I don't have to rely on my router "detecting" my connection type for half an eternity?

Comment: If everything was set back to factory defaults.  I wonder if you have to re-enter your ISP credentials to connect to the ISP and obtain a DHCP address.

Comment: @pythonian That is a possibility. But given that I can connect my laptop directly to the modem via ethernet without needing credentials, would the router still need a password to go online?

Comment: Not sure.  Every modem I have configured requires the user to configure the creds on the WAN port.  I am not familiar with your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue by connecting directly to my router via an Ethernet cable, then pointing my browser to http://router.asus.com, where it immediately informed me that I *did* have internet connectivity.

I initially tried to reconfigure my ASUS router via WiFi because my MacBook doesn't have an Ethernet port, and that's when I was running into the issue. It took me a few days to get ahold of a Windows laptop with an Ethernet port, but when I plugged it in, it was a very quick and painless setup process.

Moral of the story: Don't perform a firmware upgrade on your router if you don't have an Ethernet port and cable with which to configure it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

just go to 
WAN

there is a box for mac address and next to it there is a MAC clone button click it then click apply and that should solve it.